# Can I implement an interface and have it as a field when returning it?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, interface

I know it sounds trivial, but is it somehow possible to return the b field when i pass an A variable to a function which expects an IMyIntercace? Then i don't have to implement the Hello() function in the class A, instead i just return b as the IMyInterface.

```
interface IMyInterface
{
    void Hello();
}
class A : IMyInterface
{
    B b = new B();
}
class B : IMyInterface
{
    public void Hello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void foo(IMyInterface myInterface)
    {
        myInterface.Hello();
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A someVariable = new A();
        foo(someVariable);
    }
}
```

I suppose it cant be done, but is there any design pattern or trick that could do it?

**EDIT**

The reason i dont want to derive A is because maybe i want to do this

```
class A : IMyInterface
{
    B b = new B();
    B b2 = new B();
    IMyInterface bPointer;
}
```

Then i can point to one of the b's depending on some situation

Comment: Why have you such need? Design will depend on what do  you want to achieve?

Comment: Why not `class A : B`?

Answer (score 0):

You could inherit A from B.
A will continue to implement the interface and you may override every function you need to change in the future.

```
interface IMyInterface
{
    void Hello();
}
class A : B
{

}
class B : IMyInterface
{
    public void Hello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No. Either `A` implements `IMyInterface`, in which case you don't need to do anything, or it does not, in which case there is no way to automatically "redirect" any interested parties to the `b` member.

You can either expose `b` (and preferably make it a property) to the outside world so that they can refer to it as required, or you can make `A` implement `IMyInterface` and manually forward all calls to `b` like this:

```
class A : IMyInterface
{
    B b = new B();

    public void Hello()
    {
        b.Hello();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make `A.b` public (or internal) and then call `foo(someVariable.b)`.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to have is interface delegation and unfortunately there is nothing built into the language to help you with that.

Basically, the `A` class has to implement the interface.

One way it can do that is of course to derive from `B`:

```
class A : B
{
}
```

But if you don't want to do that, then you need to delegate. What you have to do is to implement the delegation yourself so that you can delegate the responsibility of the actual implementation to the `B` class, you won't get any help from the compiler to fix this.

```
class A : IMyInterface
{
    B b = new B();

    public void Hello()
    {
        b.Hello();
    }
}
```

Comment: Inheritance should not be suggested as the solution to a "mechanical" problem. Either it makes sense in the domain model for A to extend B, or it does not.